# Save form data with jQuery and cookies?

Tags: php, jquery

**The Question:**

What Id like to know is how can I save the form data in case a user accidentally refreshes the page or gets redirected for some reason (anything can happen and I would like to store the cookie).

**My Logic:**

I spent time learning to use `$_SESSION`, and it works nicely, except it's only useful to save data once the form has been submitted, I cant seem to get it to work with page refresh.

I guess my logic on the operation is NOT accurate but I think $_SESSION just doesn't save data on refresh (im probably wrong, but since there are so many ways to save, cookies in PHP, cookies in jQuery, etc it gets kind of confusing).

So I am unsure if $_SESSIONS just works when the form is submitted, I am pretty sure that is the case though, and cookies only saves on refresh.

**Extra:**

Yesterday I wrote up a $_SESSIONS statement and if I remember correctly it was saving the form check boxes on refresh, but I messed with some code today and the check boxes only remain checked based on the form submitted checks.

**Snippet:**

```
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden" class="<?php echo $_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] ?>" value="0" />    
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_0" <?php echo ($questvalue['memory_0'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
```

This is just a snippet of one checkbox input just to show you.

**$_SESSION:**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   //user posted variable
   $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];

   $questvalue = $_SESSION['value'];

   if(isset($_POST['personalization_result'])) {   
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['personalization_result']; } 
   else {
    $_SESSION['value'] = '';  
   }

}
```

In the actual code I have more but this just the meat of the `$_SESSION`

Comment: what did you mess up? require your code please

Comment: I just added some bits of the code... I dont think I actually messed anything up I ctrl-z and reverted back to most of the code I had prior but the checkboxes arent saving on refresh.. I am thinking cookies is what I need... and if so, how do I implement a jquery cookie plugin? it looks confusing

Comment: I would check this out http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/

Comment: checking it out and looks cool so far.. hope its a breeze to setup

Comment: Yeah got it up and running, works well..